# Method Called from Delegate not passing variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building an RPG with in-field enemies. Upon contact with an enemy object, the game will go to a separate screen. When the player comes back, the monster on the in-field screen should disappear. I cannot seem to get the "bool alive" to shift.

I am declaring the bool up front. I am using an if statement in the update to determine the behavior of the mob on the in-field menu. It passes data, and debug codes but does not change the value of alive. I have tried every permutation I can think of ( this.alive = false; this.alive != alive; this.Alive = false, this.Alive = !Alive, this.Alive = !alive etc)

```
public bool alive;
public bool Alive {get; set;}


void Awake (){
        //get player target
        player = FindObjectOfType<PartyController>();
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        EventController.OnBattleCompleted += Kill;
    }

 void Update() {

    if(alive){
    //stuff that works fine
            }

    else if (!alive)
        {
        Die();
        }
    }


public void Kill()
    {
        this.alive = false;
        Debug.Log("This should be false");
    }

    public void Die ()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
```

When I tried to run the SetActive(false) directly, I was told it was still trying to interact with the object, so I figured I needed to wait to run Die (which turns off the instance) after Awake and Start, so the idea is that it comes back from the battle and runs Kill(), and then on the first update frame it runs Die.

Kill DOES run. I get the debug message.

Further, the update logic also works. If I click off the boolean in the Unity GUI, the mob despawns.

EDIT:

When I run this.alive = false; in update(), it works immediately. Running kill sets the debug message, but does not set this.alive. Running Kill() from Update similarly works.

The issue seems to be in why the method Kill() won't pass the variable in the specific context of being invoked via the eventcontroller

Comment: Your code is very long. try to provide shorter answers people will be more likely to answer you.  in this case, try to pass the boolean as ``` ref` ``` in the desired function, might be exactly what you need. tell me if it worked so I can know whether to post it as a detailed answare or not.

Comment: He is not passing the variable anywhere, so there is no place to pass as `ref`. Further it is a class variable so is the same one throughout any instance of the class.

Comment: Remove `Alive` as you are not using it. Make `alive` private so it can't be set from outside the class. Now, you may see a different error which will pinpoint the real problem - `alive` is definitely being set to `false` in `Kill()` so that is not the problem.

Comment: "alive" is not being set to false in kill. 

1) Run into monster
2) Fight monster
3) All code works but that part of kill works as intended, "alive" is still set to true in the inspector